# How to convert a checkpoint to a Keras .h5 model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, checkpoint

I have a tensorflow model that saves checkpoints, but I need to to load the weights and save the Kereas .h5 model. How can I do that?

Comment: What is your checkpoint saving as? Im assuming **.model**?

Comment: Try to provide a snippet of your code and more details on how you would like to store the checkpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you need to convert your previous checkpoint into .h5

Given an already trained model, you want to load its weights and save as **.h5**. I am assuming you have it saved as a **.model** file. Lets say it was called **first.model**

In your script, you will want to use load_model, loading your checkpoint with

```
model = load_model('first.model')
```

then you will simply need to use

```
model.save('goal.h5')
```

to save as a .h5 file.

For future reference, you can avoid this conversion process by saving checkpoints as .h5:

When using the Checkpoints feature, you have the option to save as either a **.model** **.h5**, or **.hdf5**. The line might look something like this:

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("**FILE_NAME_HERE**.model",monitor='val_loss',verbose=1,mode='min',save_best_only=True,save_weights_only=False,period=1)
```

That is how you save your checkpoint as a .model, but to save it as a h5 as you are looking to do:

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("**FILE_NAME_HERE**.h5",monitor='val_loss',verbose=1,mode='min',save_best_only=True,save_weights_only=False,period=1)
```